# Changing colors on bootstrap buttons and dropdown-toggle

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button group as below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs  red-outline-button"> Sync </button>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs  gold-outline-button" data-toggle="dropdown">New PG </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#"> Test1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Test2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.red-outline-button:hover {
  border-color: #C4213C;
  background-color: #f8d3d9;
  color: #000
}

.gold-outline-button:hover {
  border-color: #B3892F;
  background-color: #f4ebd7;
  color: #000;
}
```

The above works. When I hover the mouse over the buttons, the color changes. However, When I click and hold or click the second button to reveal the dropdown, then, the color switches back to the default gray.

I've tried `.red-outline-button:active` but that did not help.

My question is, what is the right way to set css colour when:

1. Button is pressed
2. Dropdown is opened (only the button. I don't need to style the actual dropdown

Comment: "When I click and hold or click the second button... ...I've tried `.red-outline-button:active`...": your *second* button doesn't have the `.red-outline-button` class.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Not but in the CSS we can see `.gold-outline-button:hover` which is what the second one use. So same thing really, there was little point saying he tried both when both are clearly posted.

Comment: @GillesC OP implies that the *second* button is the problem, not the first.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Maybe so, but that wouldn't make the question confusing as the question is clearly how to override the default styling of the button and attempt to do just that for both button is posted.

Comment: Did my answert help you? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to override the *default* Bootstrap classes:

```
 .btn-default.focus, .btn-default:focus
```

This will work in case you don't want to override all:

```
.gold-outline-button:hover, .gold-outline-button.focus, .gold-outline-button:focus {
  border-color: #B3892F;
  background-color: #f4ebd7;
  color: #000;
}
```

Working demo: http://www.bootply.com/Li7tkXlF9P

Hope it helps you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.gold-outline-button:focus` to the selector and `!important` the the styles to override the default Bootstrap styles.

e.g.

```
.gold-outline-button:hover, .gold-outline-button:focus {
  border-color: #B3892F !important;
  background-color: #f4ebd7 !important;
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

This should solve both Problems. See it in action here: https://jsfiddle.net/sytc4pc5/

Comment: Eww. `!important` is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: Did you see in your crystal ball in which order the OP loads his css files?

Comment: The order of the CSS files doesn't matter too much. It's all down to [Specificity](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/css/450/cascading-and-specificity#t=201611231204201693706).

Answer (score 0):

This would fix it  click is another event will not take hover properties

```
 .red-outline-button:hover,.red-outline-button:active,.red-outline-button:focus {
      border-color: #C4213C;
      background-color: #f8d3d9;
      color: #000
    }

    .gold-outline-button:hover,.gold-outline-button:active,.gold-outline-button:focus {
      border-color: #B3892F;
      background-color: #f4ebd7;
      color: #000;
    }
```